# How to re-use connections in node-resque?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, resque

I am using the [`node-resque`](https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque) API as described in the documentation. And every time I perform an enqueue a new client connection as confirmed with `CLIENT LIST` gets created. Why isn't it possible to do this all over just one connection?

```
// Initialize in the beginning and making queue globally accessible
var queue = new NR.queue({connection: connectionDetails}, jobs);
queue.on('error', function(error){ console.log(error); });

// calling this multiple times
queue.connect(function(){
  queue.enqueue('math', "add", [1,2]);
  queue.enqueue('math', "add", [1,2]);
  queue.enqueue('math', "add", [2,3]);
  queue.enqueueIn(3000, 'math', "subtract", [2,1]);
});
```

Am I misusing the API or is it a flaw in the API? You would expect that at the end of the the `connect` block it closes the connection again.

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? Ive been facing the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

The 'connect' function does not get closed unless you close it. But you can connect once and then enqueue outside the connection callback. There should be no need to call connect multiple times, you just need to ensure the connection is established before you begin adding jobs. This method does not spawn new connections to Redis.

```
var connected = false;
queue.connect(function() {
    connected = true;
});

function addJobToQueue(job) {
    if (connected) {
        queue.enqueue(job[0], job[1], job[2]);
    } else {
        setTimeout(addJobToQueue.bind(null, job), 100);
    }
}

addJobToQueue(['math', "add", [1, 2]]);
addJobToQueue(['math', "add", [2, 2]]);
addJobToQueue(['math', "add", [3, 2]]);
//..etc
```